Synchronizing a Sharepoint Folder to Git
I have a Teams Channel where Admins upload their Scripts. We want to establish a Cloud Flow that checks for new files and triggers via HTTP Post a Pipeline which uploads everything in that Teams Folder into a Azure DevOps Repo. My Question is what is the best way to authenticate the Pipeline to SharePoint.
I currently find no suitable Way.
I tried using the Link from the Share Option in Sharepoint but its refusing to connect. Should i use a Managed Identity TM or a ServicePrincipal TM or maybe just a new user and use the login credentials.

Why not get admin to upload their scripts directly to the DevOps Repo?

We have many admins, and I aim to improve their security without changing their workflows. Introducing new processes is tough when the benefits aren't obvious. For instance, they'd question why switch from Teams to another platform if they don't see a clear advantage. I know the advantage but i lack the skills of selling it

Try it the other way around. Use PowerAutomate or Logic Apps, Functions to trigger on the File modified event and then use the DevOps API to Post that file to the repo.
However I think, it is easier to teach your admins git instead of developing this.

For anyone attempting something similar, I successfully implemented this using Power Automate. Here's a detailed breakdown of my approach:

Triggering the Flow:
Start the flow with a SharePoint trigger, specifically "When a file is created or modified (properties only)."

Retrieving Necessary Values:
Fetch required values from Azure Key Vault.

Getting File Content:
Use a SharePoint flow action to get the file content. This action requires the Identifier parameter from the trigger body.

Handling Multiple Files:
Incorporate logic to determine if one or multiple files are created or modified.

Pushing to the Repository:
Perform an HTTP POST API call to push the file(s) to the Azure DevOps repository.
For detailed API documentation, refer to  Azure DevOps REST API - Pushes.


